# Adding values in two diff columns in ms access using sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Hey I was wondering you know how its possible to use "-" to subtract in the SELECT part of a query. So can you also use "+" to add? I've tried that and instead of adding the values together it does this 123+0.28=1230.28  does that maybe have anything to do with the number being in text format? But I hadn't ever changed format from when i used "-" and that worked . Thanks

my code :

```
INSERT INTO Table( Question, Calculation)

SELECT DISTINCT 'Addition' AS Question,(T2.Calculation + T1.Calculation) AS Calculation

FROM Some_Table T2, Some_Table T1

ORDER BY T2.Question;
```

Comment: @Paul Sonier Thanks! ive not yet gotten very used to making the code look nice lol

Comment: Please include the table structure for Some_table. But sure, you can add and subtract numbers. It would turn into a string if it started that way.

Comment: @Ariel hey thank you but the problem already got fixed

Comment: `-` only makes sense as a numeric subtraction, so the values get converted to numbers, but `+` is ambiguous, it could be addition or concatenation, so it depends on the types of the values.

Comment: Yes, but in general, my experience is that the + concatenation operator will coerce strings to numbers, so this result is not expected to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can use `'+'` to add two numbers together.

```
SELECT table1.Field1, table1.Field2, Field1+field2 As SumOfFields
FROM table1;

Field1  Field2  SumOfFields
1       2       3
2       3       5
```

EDIT:
If you have strings that you want to add together then you need to convert the fields to a number: - since it was pointed out that CLng wouldn't help the OP. It have been changed to CDbl to allow for the decimal.

```
SELECT table1.Field1, table1.Field2, CDbl(Field1)+CDbl(field2) As SumOfFields
FROM table1;
```

Comment: I don't think CLng is the correct function for the OP's question because `CLng("0.28")` returns 0.

Comment: CLng was the example I used, but yes there are several different Conversion functions that can be used. if you need decimal, then CDbl or CDec. Or whatever.

Comment: Well ... yeah! "Or whatever" could also include CCur, CSng, even CVar. All of them will produce a real number from "0.28". CLng will not; it produces a whole number instead.

Comment: @HansUp since you are being a stickler, the code has been updated with CDbl to allow for decimal. :)

Comment: +1 I just couldn't understand why you refused to give the OP the solution she asked for.  :-)

Comment: i learn a lot from reading these comments LOL had to google what OP meant <--- someone who has only recently starting posting anything besides on facebook

Answer (score 4):

It might be interpreting + as string concatenation between a and b. Try "(a - 0) +  (b - 0)" to force interpretation as numbers.

Comment: If you love it, accept it as the answer. Helps people find the best answer faster.

Comment: Yep haha jsut had to wait for the few mins before u can accept answers

Answer (score 4):

If T2.Calculation and T1.Calculation are text data type, use the Val() function to transform them to numbers before addition.

```
(Val(T2.Calculation) + Val(T1.Calculation)) AS Calculation
```

**Edit**: 
When you use the minus operator with two text values (as in `"2" - "1"`), Access will transform the text values to their numerical equivalents, if possible. However, if either of the text values doesn't represent a valid number, the minus operator will give you a "Type mismatch" error ... as in `"2" - "hans"`

The plus operator works differently --- with two text values, it will attempt to concatenate them, same as if you'd used the concatenation operator (&) instead of the addition operator (+) ... `"2" + "1"` will give you "21" as a text value rather than the number 3.  So, in that specific case, `"2" + "1"` is equivalent to `"2" & "1"`.

An important distinction between the addition and concatenation operators is when one of the values is Null.  `"2" + Null` yields Null.  But `"2" & Null` yields "2".

Answer (score -1):

Just precede your formula with `0+` and it will know you're talking in numbers instead of strings:

Instead of `[A]+[B]+[C]`  put   `0+[A]+[B]+[C]`